# Ajax Cannot Post URL-String as Data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

i just was wondering why i can not pass a url String via a ajax post request. I am posting to my own Server so there is no CORS issue i guess.

When i am trying todo this:

```
var url = $(".testInput").val();
$.post("api.php", {addSong: url});
```

i am getting a 403 Forbidden from my php file.

[image]

But as soon i am doing this:

```
var url = $(".testInput").val().replace("http://", "").replace("https://","");
$.post("api.php", {addSong: url});
```

i get a 200 okay from the server and it all works fine and perfectly.

[image]

Comment: the first example, input contains soundcloud url which is differnt from your local url

Comment: yes it contains a url but it's still a string which i am sending to a local url

Comment: sorry I didn't see, That shouldn't happen, I have also tested on my side and it's working no errors

Comment: Sounds like something in your php validation

Comment: Well i also tested this locally and all worked perfect. But when i upload this to my Webspace it has this crazy behavior. Maybe some weird Serversettings my Webspace Provider has made? That is forbidden to post url's in ajax requests?